# How to extract certain data using groupby and use the extracted data to make a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

[image]

So i have dataset of movie name, date , revenue accumulated. there are multiple rows for same movie and there is a column which shows the accumulated revenue. I want to extract the last accumulated revenue for a certain movie and make a new column and insert the extracted value on the first row of a certain movie.
For example, i wanna know how to extract last revenue of movie 'a', last revenue of movie 'b'.. and insert these values on the first row of new column for each movie. SO in the picture that would be D2 for movie a, D33 movie b and so on...

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 
df = df.sort_values('Date') 
df.groupby('Movie name')['Revenue accumulated'].last()`

Comment: So, if you want this column to contain an entry for the first row, what should other rows contain for that movie?

Comment: i want them to be just blank spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following. But I would recommend replacing them with `np.nan` (i.e. not blank) as this is should be a numeric column at the end.

```
def get_last_as_first(grp):
  return  pd.Series([grp.iloc[-1]] + [np.nan]*(grp.shape[0]-1))

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 
df = df.sort_values('Date')
new_col = df.groupby('Movie name')['Revenue accumulated'].transform(get_last_as_first)
```

Comment: this works fine but changes the original order of  movies . How can i do the same work,  but maintain the original movie??

Comment: @Poryuijax When you say the order of the movies changed, can you elaborate what you mean. It should be in the same order you passed the data in (as your movie column is sorted).